# python Tkinter clear certain label of there output text

Tags: python, tkinter

ive wrote some code that writes an output to the screen and it can do this multiple times the problem is i cant seem to get the text before to clear before i write over it so it just looks a bit terrible ive tried using the

```py
tk.delete(0, END)
```

but thats has done nothing to help so im not sure what to do here is the code if you want to look :

```py
entry1 = tk.Entry(root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

def encrypt ():
    
    x1 = entry1.get()
        
    try :
        val = int(x1)
    except ValueError :
        label4 = tk.Label(root, text= encryption.encryption(x1) , font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
        canvas1.create_window(200, 250, window=label4)
    else :
        label4 = tk.Label(root, text= encryption.decryption(int(x1)) , font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
        canvas1.create_window(200, 250, window=label4)        
    
    label3 = tk.Label(root, text= 'The new encrypted message is : ',font=('helvetica', 10))
    canvas1.create_window(200, 210, window=label3)
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='Encrypt data', command=encrypt , bg='brown', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)
```

i need it to write over the output label which is label4 by the way.

Comment: Create label4 outside `encrypt()` and update its text inside that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to create `label3` and `label4` outside `encrypt()` function:

```py
label3 = tk.Label(root, text='The new encrypted message is:', font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(200, 210, window=label3, state='hidden', tag='result') # initially hidden

label4 = tk.Label(root, font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 250, window=label4, state='hidden', tag='result') # initially hidden
```

Then update `label4` and make `label3` and `label4` visible inside `encrypt()`:

```py
def encrypt():
    x1 = entry1.get()
    try:
        val = int(x1)
    except ValueError:
        label4.config(text=encryption.encryption(x1))
    else:
        label4.config(text=encryption.decryption(val))
    # make label3 and label4 visible
    canvas1.itemconfig('result', state='normal')
```

Answer (score 1):

Labels don't have a delete method, you just change the text.

```
label4['text'] = ""
```

Or

```
label4.config(text="")
```

Comment: label4 is a `Label` widget which does not have `delete()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Right you are! Its a label not an Entry.